# Update Database Android

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how to update the database in android. I created an app with an embedded database. I changed the version of the database in the manifest and created the on update method. I wanted to test it to see if the database was updating properly but when I use the adb command only the -r will allow me to do a reinstall but it keeps the database. Is there a way to run the adb command that will allow me to update the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I would handle my updateRow method:

```
public void updateRow(long rowId, String code, String name) {
      ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
      args.put("code", code);
      args.put("name", name);
      db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, "_id=" + rowId, null);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for multiple rows simultaneously, rather than calling `update` for each?

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is changing the version number for the database. This is the constant number that is used by the onCreate() method of your content provider. Something similar works if you don't use a content provider for your database, and query it directly. See source code example [here](http://code.google.com/p/aegis-shield/source/browse/trunk/Aegis%20Shield/src/com/googlecode/aegisshield/db/AegisDatabaseHelper.java).

Comment: This blog post explains a bit the basics of how Android does database upgrades - http://www.unwesen.de/2009/09/07/android-development-database-upgrades/2/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following resources and see if they're helpful:

Delicious Bookmarks
http://delicious.com/tag/android+adb
http://delicious.com/tag/android+database

DevX: Creating and Using Databases in Android
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842

Learning Android: Database Programming
http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-database.html

Android Database Package Summary
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html

Comment: thanks for the links but I did not see anything that talked about doing an adb reinstall and updating the database. Is it possible to do this, my app creates that database fine the first time but only during the updates is when it crashes. Is there a manifest entry I need to enter?

Comment: never mind I found out what I was doing wrong, after some research I found out that I was not dropping the table correctly and when I would recreate the table it would error out. I ended up dropping the table correctly and instead of calling the oncreate command I just wrote a query to recreate the table in the onupdate method.

Comment: I think it would be more constructive if you offered examples instead of a bunch of (unrelated) links.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is changing the version number parameter that I provide to the DBOpenHelper class which extends the SQLiteOpenHelper (the class used for creating/read/writing/etc... the Android database). When the version number parameter is incremented, the onUpdate() function is called once for the new value of this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If by updating you mean rebuilding (as I do during development when I want to start with a fresh database every time my application starts) then add this code before you access the database in your application:

```
this.getContext().getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase(DATABASENAME);
```

**OR**

Find the path to your database:

```
SQLiteHelper sql_database_helper = new SQLiteHelper(this.getContext().getApplicationContext());
File dbFile = getDatabasePath(DATABASENAME);
Log.v("XIX","DB FILE PATH:"+dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Then delete your database from the command prompt:

```
> adb devices
List of devices attached
3246%$%^$&17   device  
> adb shell
$ su 
su
rm mydatapath
```

NOTE: You may not be able to access the `su` command without cracking your phone

Explanation:
If you don't want to follow the advice given by r1k0 (which is probably the right way to do it if you are upgrading an already release app) then you can just delete the database with the following adb commands and a restart of your app will call the onCreate method again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't advise to use this way:

```
public void updateRow(long rowId, String code, String name) {
      ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
      args.put("code", code);
      args.put("name", name);
      db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, "_id=" + rowId, null);
}
```

Your app will be vulnerable to sql injection attack, the best way to do that is something like this:

```
public void updateRow(long rowId, String code, String name) {
      ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
      args.put("code", code);
      args.put("name", name);
      String whereArgs[] = new String[1];
      whereArgs[0] = "" + rowId;
      db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, "_id= ?", whereArgs);
}
```