# Upgrading a database keeping the older version

Tags: android

i have to kept the older database and to upgrade the newly added items to the database.Is it possible to store the old table????????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097657/update-database-android

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to update an older database stored from a previous version of your application?

Comment: The title suggest, that the old version should be kept, the question suggest that it should be updated. So what do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

> A helper class to manage database creation and version management. You
>   create a subclass implementing onCreate(SQLiteDatabase),
>   onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and optionally
>   onOpen(SQLiteDatabase), and this class takes care of opening the
>   database if it exists, creating it if it does not, and **upgrading it as
>   necessary**. Transactions are used to make sure the database is always
>   in a sensible state.

Answer (score 0):

We can upgrade the version

```
public class MyscreenDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {




    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="myscreenDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=33;



    private static final String MyScreen_CREATE="create table MyScreentb(_id integer primary key autoincrement,userid real," +
            "password real,email real,address real,phoneno real,rectype integer)";


    public MyscreenDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
System.out.println("table created....");
          try{
        db.execSQL(MyScreen_CREATE);
          }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(MyscreenDatabaseHelper.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from"+oldVersion+"to"+newVersion+",which will Distroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todo");
     onCreate(db);  
    }



}
```

Comment: This will do upgradation by dropping the old table,and the previous data will not be stored in the database.